# How to call a function in Python

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to call the time.time function to achieve the time since epoch

```
import time

myFile = open("txt.txt", "w")
myFile.write(f"{time.time}")
myFile.close()
```

however, this writes "< built-in function time >" to txt.txt

How do I call on the function to write time since epoch?

Comment: You need to call the function `time.time()`

Comment: `time.time()` call the function and return the time, while `time.time` is the function object itself, notice the missing `()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the function using brackets.

```
import time


myFile = open("wall.txt", "w")
myFile.write(f"({time.time()})\n")
myFile.close()
```

Comment: Wrong conclusion, see the two comments to your question.  You need to call the function to get the time.